# fadeIn() - flickering images in Firefox

Tags: jquery

Demo-site: `http://83.249.244.210:8080/img/`

Try refreshing the site a few times in Firefox. When the images fade in, some of them flicker a bit. Can anyone please explain why?

This is how i load my images:

```
$(function(){

        $.post('service.php?getPhotos', function(data){

            var loadCount = 0;

            $.each(data, function(){

                $.post('service.php?getImage', { id: this.id }, function(data2){

                    loadCount++;

                    var $galleryItem = $('<div/>')
                        .hide()
                        .attr({ 'class': 'galleryItem' })
                        .html('<a href="'+ data2.photo.id +'"><img src="http://farm'+ data2.photo.farm +'.staticflickr.com/'+ data2.photo.server +'/'+ data2.photo.id +'_'+ data2.photo.secret + '_q.jpg"/></a><h3>'+ data2.photo.title._content +'</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing.</p>');

                    $('#container').append($galleryItem); 

                    $galleryItem.find('img').load(function(){

                        $galleryItem.fadeIn(200);
                    });

                });

            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: I don't see any "flickering" I did see what looked to me like a pause mid `fadeIn()`.  Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @Jared Yes, a pause, or maybe a blink. Not sure what to call it :)

Comment: Since you commented elsewhere that you think it might be css related you might edit your question and include that info.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to hide the image with css before jQuery fades it in?

```
#container > div {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Same result im afraid. Thanks though

Comment: If its any consolation, its running fine on Firefox 13.0.1 (Mac OS)

Comment: Could it be that the img tag exists but the browser has not retrieved  the image itself from flickr before trying to fade it in? i.e. does load get called when the img tag exists or when the img is fully downloaded from flickr?

Comment: It has been retrieved and completly loaded into the browser inside the load function.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will change anything but you only have to bind the event once to 'load'. i.e. your code might look like

`$('#container img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeIn(200);
});`

Comment: My load method already works. And i dont think you can use `on` with `load`. I think my problem is css related, so ill dig deeper in to that now. Thanks :)